# Get user's locale on BotFramework

Tags: botframework

I know that it's possible on Fb by taking the userId from the session object and using the User Profile API.

I would like to be able to get it for any channel and not just Fb.

Does anyone know if is there any way to get the user's locale from the session object or in some way that doesn't require to use any API?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it straight from the activity object.  I am doing it from a Message Activity which I get from my dialog context - something like this:

```
IMessageActivity msg = context.Activity.AsMessageActivity();
string locale = msg.Locale;
```

However, I wouldn't rely on this entirely as it does seem like it is channel dependent, some implement, and some don't.